# Oracle pivot a table based on column value using like

Tags: sql, oracle

sample table

```
Child    Parent
FF00001  12345
AA00002  12345
GG00003  12345
TT00003  12345
```

What I want is a table like this

```
Parent  FF        AA        GG      TT 
12345  FF00001    AA00002  GG00003  TT00003
```

The numbers after the first 2 letters can be anything but I know that they are always AA, FF, GG, TT etc. Can I pivot on a like statement? `like 'AA%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation like this:

```
select
    parent,
    max(case when child like 'FF%' then child end) FF,
    max(case when child like 'AA%' then child end) AA,
    max(case when child like 'GG%' then child end) GG,
    max(case when child like 'TT%' then child end) TT 
from your_table
group by parent;
```

Other way is to find the prefix in a subquery using substr and then apply pivot on it.

```
select *
from (
    select
        child,
        parent,
        substr(child, 1, 2) prefix
    from your_table
)
pivot (
    max(child) for prefix in ('FF' as FF,'AA' as AA,'GG' as GG,'TT' as TT)
)
```

Both produces:

```
PARENT  FF      AA      GG      TT
---------------------------------------
12345   FF00001 AA00002 GG00003 TT00003
```

If you have multiple values with same prefix and you want to keep them all, use `row_number()` window function in the subquery and then apply pivot:

```
with your_table (Child   , Parent) as (
    select 'FF00001', 12345 from dual union all
    select 'FF00002', 12345 from dual union all
    select 'AA00002', 12345 from dual union all
    select 'GG00003', 12345 from dual union all
    select 'TT00003', 12345 from dual
)
-- test data setup ends. See the solution below --

select parent, FF, AA, GG, TT
from (
    select
        child,
        parent,
        substr(child, 1, 2) prefix,
        row_number() over (partition by parent, substr(child, 1, 2) order by child)
    from your_table
)
pivot (
    max(child) for prefix in ('FF' as FF,'AA' as AA,'GG' as GG,'TT' as TT)
)
```

Produces:

```
PARENT  FF      AA      GG      TT
---------------------------------------
12345   FF00001 AA00002 GG00003 TT00003
12345   FF00002  -       -       -
```

Comment: I like the aggregate, but what if there are duplicates? The max will only show one row. Example FF0001 and FF0002

Comment: @Jabda - Happy to help. :-)